# Add a datetime column to multiple dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to loop through a list of dataframes and append a datetime column to each. I've tried the following to no avail:

```
dfs = ['nov22_2017', 'nov29_2017', 'dec06_2017','dec13_2017', 
       'dec20_2017', 'dec27_2017', 'jan03_2018', 'jan10_2018']
sheets = ['11.22.17', '11.29.17', '12.6.17', '12.13',
          '12.20', '12.27', '1.3.18', '1.10.18']
dates = ['2017-11-22', '2017-11-29', '2017-1-06', '2017-12-13',
         '2017-12-20', '2017-12-27', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-10']

# create a list of datetimes
datetimes = [pd.to_datetime(date) for date in dates]

# assign each df to a variable
dfs = [nrc_xl.parse(sheet, usecols = 10) for sheet in sheets]

# assign datetime columns
for index, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df['date'] = datetimes[index]
```

The for loop doesn't modify the dataframes in the list. How do I accomplish this programmatically without having to create and assign a column for each dataframe?

EDIT: I fixed it.

```
sheets = ['11.22.17', '11.29.17', '12.6.17', '12.13',
          '12.20', '12.27', '1.3.18', '1.10.18']

# assign dfs to variables
[nov22_2017, nov29_2017, dec06_2017, dec13_2017,
 dec20_2017, dec27_2017, jan03_2018, jan10_2018] = [nrc_xl.parse(sheet, usecols = 10) for sheet in sheets]

dfs = [nov22_2017, nov29_2017, dec06_2017, dec13_2017,
       dec20_2017, dec27_2017, jan03_2018, jan10_2018]

# create a list of datetimes
dates = ['2017-11-22', '2017-11-29', '2017-1-06', '2017-12-13',
         '2017-12-20', '2017-12-27', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-10']

datetimes = [pd.to_datetime(date) for date in dates]

# assign datetime columns
for index, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df['date'] = datetimes[index]
```

Comment: Aren't you already doing this programmatically? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: The for loop doesn't modify the dataframes in the list. When I check the columns, there is no date column for any of them.

Comment: I find that surprising, considering `df`s are mutable, and assigning a column inside the loop should update the original.

Comment: why not do just for df in dfs: df['date']=datetimes . Because using enumerate doesn't update the original dataframes . If you do for df in dfs: df['date']=datetimes you will get the original dataframes with date column.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this part of your list comprehension:

```
# assign each df to a variable
dfs = [nrc_xl.parse(sheet, usecols = 10).assign(date=datetimes[i]) \
       for i, sheet in enumerate(sheets)]
```